# HTML Email Table with Hatched background

Tags: html, css

Im building a html email to send out, I realise its better to use tables rather than divs, but one of the sections i would like to a hatched background like our corporate website (services section):
http://lasersurveying.com/

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply this to your table or whatever your email's content is contained within:

```
style="background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAB4AAAAeAAgMAAABSzKJVAAAADFBMVEVMaXGZmZmZmZmZmZnjntakAAAABHRSTlMACnxgcDy07gAAD71JREFUeF7t2zEKwkAURdEBe/dj5xJdpAsRDBb2IeTnHhs5/cD9BN56ru/vvf3dL0Zc2+/22v4fVyMGXjJe+Oli4CWjdy7BKMGDKcEowSjBKMEowSjBKMESjBKMEowSjBKMEowSLMEowSjBKMEowSjBKMG4rv2S0brQuhDd0uiWRrc0+pyFEowSLMEowSjBKMEowSjBO1CCUYJRglGCUYJRglGCJRglGCUYJRglGCUYJViC0boQrQvRuhDd0uiWRrc0eucSjBKMEowSjBKMEowSLMEtSjBKMEowSjBKMEowSrAEowSjBKMEowSjBKMESzBaF6J1IVoXolsa3dLolkbvXIJRglGCUYJRglGCUYIluEYJRglGCUYJRglGCUYJlmCUYJRglGCUYJRglGAJRutCtC5E60J0S6NbGt3S6J1LMEowSjBKMEowSjBKsATXKMEowSjBKMEowSjBKMESjBKMEowSjBKMEowSLMFoXYjWhWhdiG5pdEujWxq9cwlGCUYJRglGCUYJRgmW4BolGCUYJRglGCUYJRglWIJRglGCUYJRglGCUYIlGK0L0boQrQvRLY1uaXRLo3cuwSjBKMEowSjBKMEowRJcowSjBKMEowSjBKMEowRLMEowSjBKMEowSjBKsASjdSFaF6J1Ibql0S2Nbmn0ziUYJRglGCUYJRglGCVYgmuUYJRglGCUYJRglGCUYAlGCUYJRglGCUYJRgmWYLQuROtCtC5EtzS6pdEtjd65BKMEowSjBKMEowSjBEtwjRKMEowSjBKMEowSjBIswSjBKMEowSjBKMEowRKM1oVoXYjWheiWRrc0uqXRO5dglGCUYJRglGCUYJRgCa5RglGCUYJRglGCUYJRgiUYJRglGCUYJRglGCVYgtG6EK0L0boQ3dLolka3NHrnEowSjBKMEowSjBKMEizBNUowSjBKMEowSjBKMEqwBKMEowSjBKMEowSjBEswWheidSFaF6JbGt3S6JZG71yCUYJRglGCUYJRglGCJbhGCUYJRglGCUYJRglGCZZglGCUYJRglGCUYJRgCUbrQrQuROtCdEujWxrd0uidSzBKMEowSjBKMEowSrAE1yjBKMEowSjBKMEowSjBEowSjBKMEowSjBKMEizBaF2I1oVoXYhuaXRLo1savXMJRglGCUYJRglGCUYJluAaJRglGCUYJRglGCUYJViCUYJRglGCUYJRglGCJRitC9G6EK0L0S2Nbml0S6N3LsEowSjBKMEowSjBKMESXKMEowSjBKMEowSjBKMESzBKMEowSjBKMEowSrAEo3UhWheidSG6pdEtjW5p9M4lGCUYJRglGCUYJRglWIJrlGCUYJRglGCUYJRglGAJRglGCUYJRglGCUYJlmC0LkTrQrQuRLc0uqXRLY3euQSjBKMEowSjBKMEowRLcI0SjBKMEowSjBKMEowSLMEowSjBKMEowSjBKMESjNaFaF2I1oXolka3NLql0TuXYJRglGCUYJRglGCUYAkOUoJRglGCUYJRglGCUYIlGCUYJRglGCUYJRglWILRuhCtC9G6EN3S6JZGtzR65xKMEowSjBKMEowSjBIswSjBKMEowSjBKMEowRKMEowSjBKMEowSjBKM3rkEZ2hdiNaFaF2Ibml0S6NbGn/0ziV4KnHm40QJxp0TjBKMEowSjBKMEizBKMEowSjBKMEowSjBEowSjBKMEowSjBKMEoxz14VoXYjLutAtjW5pdEujz1kowSjBKMESjBKMEowSjBJ8DCUYJRglGCUYJRglGCVYglGCUYJRglGCUYJRgiUYrQvRuhCtC9EtjW5pdEujdy7BKMEowSjBKMEowSjBElyjBKMEowSjBKMEowSjBEswSjBKMEowSjBKMEqwBKN1IVoXonUhuqXRLY1uafTOJRglGCUYJRglGCUYJViCa5RglGCUYJRglGCUYJRgCUYJRglGCUYJRglGCZZgtC5E60K0LkS3NLql0S2N3rkEowSjBKMEowSjBKMES3CNEowSjBKMEowSjBKMEizBKMEowSjBKMEowSjBEozWhWhdiNaF6JZGtzS6pdE7l2CUYJRglGCUYJRglGAJrlGCUYJRglGCUYJRglGCJRglGCUYJRglGCUYJViC0boQrQvRuhDd0uiWRrc0eucSjBKMEowSjBKMEowSLME1SjBKMEowSjBKMEowSrAEowSjBKMEowSjBKMESzBaF6J1IVoXolsa3dLolkbvXIJRglGCUYJRglGCUYIluEYJRglGCUYJRglGCUYJlmCUYJRglGCUYJRglGAJRutCtC5E60J0S6NbGt3S6J1LMEowSjBKMEowSjBKsATXKMEowSjBKMEowSjBKMESjBKMEowSjBKMEowSLMFoXYjWhWhdiG5pdEujWxq9cwlGCUYJRglGCUYJRgmW4BolGCUYJRglGCUYJRglWIJRglGCUYJRglGCUYIlGK0L0boQrQvRLY1uaXRLo3cuwSjBKMEowSjBKMEowRJcowSjBKMEowSjBKMEowRLMEowSjBKMEowSjBKsASjdSFaF6J1Ibql0S2Nbmn0ziUYJRglGCUYJRglGCVYgmuUYJRglGCUYJRglGCUYAlGCUYJRglGCUYJRgmWYLQuROtCtC5EtzS6pdEtjd65BKMEowSjBKMEowSjBEtwjRKMEowSjBKMEowSjBIswSjBKMEowSjBKMEowRKM1oVoXYjWheiWRrc0uqXRO5dglGCUYJRglGCUYJRgCa5RglGCUYJRglGCUYJRgiUYJRglGCUYJRglGCVYgtG6EK0L0boQ3dLolka3NHrnEowSjBKMEowSjBKMEizBNUowSjBKMEowSjBKMEqwBKMEowSjBKMEowSjBEswWheidSFaF6JbGt3S6JZG71yCUYJRglGCUYJRglGCJbhGCUYJRglGCUYJRglGCZZglGCUYJRglGCUYJRgCUbrQrQuROtCdEujWxrd0uidSzBKMEowSjBKMEowSrAE1yjBKMEowSjBKMEowSjBEowSjBKMEowSjBKMEizBaF2I1oVoXYhuaXRLo1savXMJRglGCUYJRglGCUYJluAaJRglGCUYJRglGCUYJViCUYJRglGCUYJRglGCJRitC9G6EK0L0S2Nbml0S+OObwYlGCUYJRglGL+/jd65BE8lTnmNKMGYSTBKsASjBKMEowSjBKMEowRLMEowSjBKMEowSjBaF6J1oXUhuqXRLY1uafQ5CyUYJViCUYJRglGCUYJRgnegBKMEowSjBKMEowSjBEswSjBKMEowSjBKMEqwBKN1IVoXonUhuqXRLY1uafTOJRglGCUYJRglGCUYJViCa5RglGCUYJRglGCUYJRgCUYJRglGCUYJRglGCZZgtC5E60K0LkS3NLql0S2N3rkEowSjBKMEowSjBKMES3CNEowSjBKMEowSjBKMEizBKMEowSjBKMEowSjBEozWhWhdiNaF6JZGtzS6pdE7l2CUYJRglGCUYJRglGAJrlGCUYJRglGCUYJRglGCJRglGCUYJRglGCUYJViC0boQrQvRuhDd0uiWRrc0eucSjBKMEowSjBKMEowSLME1SjBKMEowSjBKMEowSrAEowSjBKMEowSjBKMESzBaF6J1IVoXolsa3dLolkbvXIJRglGCUYJRglGCUYIluEYJRglGCUYJRglGCUYJlmCUYJRglGCUYJRglGAJRutCtC5E60J0S6NbGt3S6J1LMEowSjBKMEowSjBKsATXKMEowSjBKMEowSjBKMESjBKMEowSjBKMEowSLMFoXYjWhWhdiG5pdEujWxq9cwlGCUYJRglGCUYJRgmW4BolGCUYJRglGCUYJRglWIJRglGCUYJRglGCUYIlGK0L0boQrQvRLY1uaXRLo3cuwSjBKMEowSjBKMEowRJcowSjBKMEowSjBKMEowRLMEowSjBKMEowSjBKsASjdSFaF6J1Ibql0S2Nbmn0ziUYJRglGCUYJRglGCVYgmuUYJRglGCUYJRglGCUYAlGCUYJRglGCUYJRgmWYLQuROtCtC5EtzS6pdEtjd65BKMEowSjBKMEowSjBEtwjRKMEowSjBKMEowSjBIswSjBKMEowSjBKMEowRKM1oVoXYjWheiWRrc0uqXRO5dglGCUYJRglGCUYJRgCa5RglGCUYJRglGCUYJRgiUYJRglGCUYJRglGCVYgtG6EK0L0boQ3dLolka3NHrnEowSjBKMEowSjBKMEizBNUowSjBKMEowSjBKMEqwBKMEowSjBKMEowSjBEswWheidSFaF6JbGt3S6JZG71yCUYJRglGCUYJRglGCJbhGCUYJRglGCUYJRglGCZZglGCUYJRglGCUYJRgCUbrQrQuROtCdEujWxrd0uidSzBKMEowSjBKMEowSrAE1yjBKMEowSjBKMEowSjBEowSjBKMEowSjBKMEizBaF2I1oVoXYhuaXRLo1savXMJRglGCUYJRglGCUYJluAaJRglGCUYJRglGCUYJViCUYJRglGCUYJRglGCJRitC9G6EK0L0S2Nbml0S6N3LsEowSjBKMEowSjBKMESXKMEowSjBKMEowSjBKMESzBKMEowSjBKMEowSrAEo3UhWheidSG6pdEtjW5p9M4lGCUYJfi8lGCUYJRglGCUYJRg/OfUx4kSjN65BA8gTk8wSjBKsASjBKMEowSjBKMEowTj3HUhWhfisi50S6NbGt3S6HMWSjBKMEqwBKMEowSjBKMEH0MJRglGCUYJRglGCUYJlmCUYJRglGCUYJRglGAJRutCtC5E60J0S6NbGt3S6J1LMEowSjBKMEowSjBKsATXKMEowSjBKMEowSjBKMESjBKMEowSjBKMEowSLMFoXYjWhWhdiG5pdEujWxq9cwlGCUYJRglGCUYJRgmW4BolGCUYJRglGCUYJRglWIJRglGCUYJRglGCUYIlGK0L0boQrQvRLY1uaXRLo3cuwSjBKMEowSjBKMEowRJcowSjBKMEowSjBKMEowRLMEowSjBKMEowSjBKsASjdSFaF6J1Ibql0S2Nbmn0ziUYJRglGCUYJRglGCVYgmuUYJRglGCUYJRglGCUYAlGCUYJRglGCUYJRgmWYLQuROtCtC5EtzS6pdEtjd65BKMEowSjBKMEowSjBEtwjRKMEowSjBKMEowSjBIswSjBKMEowSjBKMEowRKM1oVoXYjWheiWRrc0uqXRO5dglGCUYJRglGCUYJRgCUYJRglGCT4RJRglGCUYJRglGCUYJViCUYJRglGCUYLRuhCtC60L0S2Nbml0S6PPWSjBKMHonUswSjBKMEowSjBKMEqwBKMEowSjBKMEowSjBEswSjBKMEowSjBKMFoX4geRwR4CsNdxhAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');"
```

I have taken http://lasersurveying.com/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/images/home/background-lines.png from your website and base64'd it, the reason for doing so being that email clients tend to block external images from loading in due to them being used for tracking and whatnot, but anything internal is generally okay.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.hashed-bg {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( -45deg, #858585, #858585 2px, #777777 2px, #777777 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="hashed-bg" style="height:100px"></div>
```

}

Comment: How would I add this to a table and add as inline CSS?

Comment: @lewis-boxer just use the following on the element of your choosing:

style="background: repeating-linear-gradient( -45deg, #858585, #858585 2px, #777777 2px, #777777 20px)"